# How would I cancel a specific event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, click, touch, swipe, drag

I added 2 different events each called `touchstart` and `mousedown` in the `on` method like this:

> `this.$el.on('touchstart mousedown', (e) => { this.start(e); })`

My main goal is to cancel a `mousedown` event ***only*** which belongs to the `on` method at the end of called `end` function.

If I run a `touchstart` event 2 different events are always firing together. See this picture:

[image]

This problem causes undesired event block at Firefox. And also the code runs twice which is unnecessary. I want to redirect the website when I `click` or `touch` the element, prevent when I `drag` or `swipe`.

I searched about how to prevent a specific event on google but haven't found any of info so I've tried few ways by myself. However, all of the cases didn't work.

1. Add `return false;` line

   - Sadly, `return false` makes stop all of the remained events after `end` function has ended. My goal is to cancel the `mousedown` only, not the entire of the `events`. Therefore I can't just put the line into the function.
2. Add `mousedown` event into the `off` method

   - This also doesn't work. The `events` which belongs to the `off` method still remains as it's turned off. So if I try to drag after I swiped the element, nothing happens because `mousedown` event is now turned off.
3. Add `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()`

   - Those can't use as the same reason of case 1.
4. Using `RegExp` to separate and make a new function for Firefox

   - The problem was firing the undesired event, not the browser.

Are there any ways to cancel a specific `event` in this code?

```js
class Evt {
  constructor($el) {
    this.$el = $el;
  }
  start(e) {
    console.log('start Function');
    this.$el.off('click');
    this.$el.on({
      ['touchmove mousemove']: (e) => this.eventmove(e),
      ['touchend mouseup']: (e) => this.end(e)
    });
  }
  eventmove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('move function');
    this.$el.on('click', (e) => {e.preventDefault();});
    return false;
  }
  end(e) {
    console.log('end function');
    this.$el.on('click');
    this.$el.off('touchmove touchend mousemove mouseup');
  }
  apply() {
    this.$el.on('touchstart mousedown', (e) => {
      this.start(e);
    })
  }
}
var thatEvt = new Evt($('#link'));
thatEvt.apply();
```

```css
      a {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: brown;
        font-family: Helvetica;
      }
```

```html
    <a id="link" href="https://google.co.uk">
      Click/Touch and Drag/Swipe
    </a>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to deregister an event handler?

Comment: @Rafael If that is going to fix my problem, then yes. Sorry I can't explain more than right now because my less vocabulary :/

Comment: @Rafael If the deregister is using `off` method, then I've tried it already which is Case 2 in the question.

Comment: I see... but you're registering click event listeners on every `eventmove()`? Why are you doing that? It looks like you should delete that line.

Comment: @Rafael If I remove that line, then `dragging` the element doesn't prevent redirecting. it opens a new browser.

Comment: @Rafael This code will going to inside of my own slider plugin. So I have to prevent the redirecting link when I dragging the element.

Comment: @Rafael I've tried your recent answer but the click event doesn't redirect the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I hear it, your intention is to have the link not redirect when the mouse is moved within a click.

Firstly, I assume you do not want the link to be draggable, so add the `draggable="false"` tag.  This will prevent events that may effect code outside what you have sent (such as redirecting/dropping links).

```html
<a id="link" href="https://google.co.uk" draggable="false">
  Click/Touch and Drag/Swipe
</a>
```

If that does not solve your issue I have put together this code below, it may be more complicated, but it should be a little more robust.

```
class Evt {
  constructor($el) {
    this.$el = $el;
    this.active = false;
    this.preventRedirect = false;
  }
  start(e) {
    console.log('start Function');
    this.active = true;
    this.preventRedirect = false;
  }
  eventmove(e) {
    if (this.active) {
      console.log('move function');
      this.preventRedirect = true;
    }
  }
  end(e) {
    if (this.active) {
      console.log('end function');
      this.active = false;
    }
  }
  apply() {
    this.$el.on({
      ['touchstart mousedown']: (e) => this.start(e),
      ['click']: (e) => { //preventing onclick only if preventRedirect is set
        if (this.preventRedirect) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
    $("html").on({ //so that the mouse can move outside the element and still work.
      ['touchmove mousemove']: (e) => this.eventmove(e),
      ['touchend mouseup']: (e) => this.end(e)
    });
  }
}
var thatEvt = new Evt($('#link'));
thatEvt.apply();
```

Comment: Ah, The way to use boolean flags might be a huge clue to solve my issue. I'm going to test and edit it with your example. Thank you so much for answering :>